# Woocommerce create account button and label overlapping on the checkout page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce store, but on the checkout page the create account label and checkbox are overlapping, I have tried all sort of css styles to separate them but it won't.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Appreciate your assistance

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Sorry how do I run that with wordpress?

Comment: Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , we need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example